# How can I use ReinerSCT Standard Chipcard Reader with Jameica/Hibiscus in Ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Tags: 14.04, pcscd

I want to use a "ReinerSCT Standard" Chipcard reader with the Jameica/Hibiscus Homebanking suite. I installed "pcsc-lite" and the "libifd-cyberjack6" package, and if I run

```
pcscd -d -f
```

I can see the card reader is discovered correctly and also detects when I insert or remove a chipcard.

However in Jameica, whatever I do the card reader is not found.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating the file

~/.jameica/cfg/de.willuhn.jameica.services.SysPropertyService.properties

and manually configuring the location of libpcsclite.so.1 in this file by adding the following line:

sun.security.smartcardio.library=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcsclite.so.1

After restarting Jameica the reader was correctly found automatically and I can finally do all my homebanking using Linux.

You may also want to have a look at this page (German):

[http://www.willuhn.de/wiki/doku.php?id=support:list:kartenleser](http://www.willuhn.de/wiki/doku.php?id=support%3alist%3akartenleser)